# Where can I find a simple ASP.NET MVC (C#) tutorial(s)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am coming from a PHP background and I am familiar with OOP concepts, but I am moving away from PHP and trying out ASP.NET MVC using C#.

Even without being forced to use web forms, this is a big jump for me coming from PHP. This is worsened by the fact that there are not very many tutorials out there on this subject in comparison to PHP.

All the tutorials I have found online are too complex or not very well put together so when I am going through them I always miss something that adds much confusion. That being said I understand the Visual Studio IDE pretty well from past experiences.

Is there any decent and simple MCV tutorial out there on the web that would be decent for a PHP programmer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been working with ASP.NET MVC since it Beta days and have always found lack of proper technical details in blogs and forum posts to be quite inhibiting in the climbing up the learning curve. Then, ScottGu, ScottHa and others posted the [Nerddiner sample application](http://www.nerddinner.com/) and the first chapter of the excellent [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611) book.

It is a good idea to look at sample code/applications and build our own blog/forum application using ASP.NET MVC while working your way through. Steven Sanderson's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079) and his [blog](http://blog.codeville.net/) are terrific resources too.

HTH,
indyfromoz

Comment: +1 The NerdDinner app is an excellent way of getting familiar with both th ASP.NET MVC concept / way of thinking (especially when you come from a ASP.NET WebForms developer's perspective) while at the same time providing some excellent sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Start with [Scott Gu's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/search.aspx?q=mvc&o=Relevance) blog. [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) has a "Learn MVC" section. Don't forget to look at the code within the default template. It's a good place to start.

Of course ask questions here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

I think Scott Hanselman's video is the best tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-7093.aspx

also this site.

http://www.asp.net/mVC/learn/

Answer (score 0):

You can always start with [ScottGu Manchester ASP.NET MVC Video](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/10/24/scottgu-manchester-asp-net-mvc-video.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC Resource Guide:

http://blogs.msdn.com/cbowen/archive/2009/10/31/asp-net-mvc-resource-guide.aspx